# VS Code reporting error in Razor files: missing assembly reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Opening a Blazor application in VS Code which also have C# Dev Kit installed. I can run the project via `dotnet watch --project MyBlazor.UI/` which works fine, but on different Razor files, VS Code is showing red lines with error

> The type or namespace name 'MainLayout' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How to fix the error in VS Code?

Update: I found that if I open `MainLayout.cs` file once, then afterwards VS Code does not complain about missing assembly reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rebuild the solution first then after that, make sure that the path of the project is correct.

Instead of `dotnet watch --project MyBlazor.UI\`, use `dotnet watch --project MyBlazor.UI`.